# socket.ConnectAsync for .net35

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

for the based project focus on the .net40, and the sokcet connection uses the "socket.ConnectAsync", now, this project need to traget .net35. this connection method doesn't support on 35. so does it have other package to support this connection? or need to re-realize this socket based on the .net35's method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the documentation is wrong, it has been supported since .Net 2.0

[ConnectAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.connectasync?view=netframework-3.5)

> Begins an asynchronous request for a connection to a remote host.

**Applies to**

> - .NET Core
>
>   - 2.1, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0
> - .NET Framework
>
>   - 4.7.2, 4.7.1, 4.7, 4.6.2, 4.6.1, 4.6, 4.5.2, 4.5.1, 4.5, 4.0, **3.5, 3.0, 2.0**
> - .NET Standard
>
>   - 2.0, 1.6, 1.4, 1.3
> - Xamarin.Android
>
>   - 7.1
> - Xamarin.iOS
>
>   - 10.8
> - Xamarin.Mac
>
>   - 3.0

Comment: sorry, it's my mistake. there has different args between 35 and 40 platform